# How to specify proper override explicitly in kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, inheritance, overriding, delegation

I have a java class as such:

```
class A {
    public void foo() {...}
}
```

Then in Kotlin, a class:

```
class B: A() {}
```

I'm extending from B, but using an interface with delegation to override `A.foo`, i.e

```kotlin
interface IFoo {
    fun foo()
}

class FooImpl: IFoo {
    override fun foo() { ... }
}
```

Here's the problem, I use it as

```kotlin
class C: B(), IFoo by FooImpl() {}
```

But I'm getting the error that `foo() hides supertype override... please specify proper override explicitly`. Where do I do this?

Comment: Kotlin doesn't support having the delegate override functions of the class it is being used by. The delegate is completely oblivious to the class that's using it. Even if the class that uses it overrides one of its methods, if one of the delegate's methods calls that overridden method, it calls its own implementation, not the override.

Comment: I got this to work: https://pl.kotl.in/vqT-4G9mG - same thing but the base class is a kotlin one (is there something different I did there?)

Comment: Oh, maybe it works with Kotlin base classes. I didn't try that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't allowed to modify the Java class, it is better to use composition

```
 class A {
    fun foo() {
        println("A")
    }
}

open class B (val a:A): IFoo {
    override fun foo(){
        a.foo()
    }
}

interface IFoo {
    fun foo()
}

class FooImpl: IFoo {
    override fun foo() { println("B") }
}
class C(): IFoo by B(A()) {} // A
//class C(): IFoo by FooImpl() {} // B

fun main(){
    val c = C()
    c.foo()
}
```